# Determine the coefficients of the power series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I want to determine the coefficients $a_n$ of the power series $\Sigma_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nz^n=\frac{1}{(1-z)^2}$, where $|z|<1$ and $a_n,z \in \mathbb{C}$.

We have $\frac{1}{1-z}=\Sigma_{n=0}^{\infty}z^n$ and so $\frac{1}{(1-z)^2}=\Sigma_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{z^n}{1-z}=\Sigma_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nz^n$.

Therefore, $a_n=\frac{1}{1-z}$. Is this correct?

Comment: No, it's not correct. The coefficients must be constants, they can't depend on $z$. Do you know how to differentiate and integrate power series?

Comment: @DanielFischer No, I do not.

Answer (score 1):

No, because $a_n$ can't depend on $z$.

Try to compute the derivative of both sides of
$$
\frac1{1-x} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n
$$instead.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that $$\Bigg[\frac{1}{1 -z}\Bigg]' = \frac{1}{(1 - z)^2}$$ and $$\frac{d}{dz}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} z^n = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} nz^{n-1}$$

Now use that $\frac{1}{1 -z} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} z^n $. Can you take it from here?